# Hide all Content types from "New button"

Tags: sharepoint-online, development

I am trying to delete the remaining content type from the new button in my library. I am getting this error constantly which is weird since I am able to make the changes through the UI. Any help would be appreciated.

```
        public async Task HideAllContentTypesInNewButtonAsync(ClientContext clientContext, string listTitle, params string[] excludedContentTypeNames)
    {
        List list = clientContext.Web.GetListByTitle(listTitle);
        await list.EnsurePropertiesAsync(toLoad => toLoad.ContentTypes, toLoad => toLoad.ContentTypes.Include(ct => ct.Name));

        var contentTypesToHide = list.ContentTypes
                                     .Where(contentType => excludedContentTypeNames.All(name => contentType.Name != name))
                                     .ToArray();

        HideContentTypesInNewButton(list, contentTypesToHide);
        list.Update();
        log.LogDebug($"Hiding Content Types on list '{listTitle}'.");

        await clientContext.ExecuteQueryRetryAsync();
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: We don't create new files we only upload files so the functionality is useless for us.

Comment: I've added an answer which explains how to hide the "New" button.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue but with PowerShell and solved this by removing all content types in the order and then creating a new list.

In this case, i pass the name of the content types in the parameter `$order = "ContentTypeA", "ContentTypeB"`

```
# Sets the content type order on list
Function Set-ContentTypeOrderOnList
{
    Param
    (
        [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
        $webUrl,
        [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
        $order,
        [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
        $rootFolder
    )

    $web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
    $list = $web.Lists | ? { $_.RootFolder.Name -eq $rootFolder }

    if($list.ContentTypes[$order[0]] -ne $null)
    {
        $currentListOrder = $list.RootFolder.ContentTypeOrder

        for($i = $currentListOrder.Count; $i -gt 0; $i--)
        {
            $lct = $currentListOrder[$i]
            $disableoutput = $currentListOrder.Remove($lct)
        }

        $currentListOrder.Add($list.ContentTypes[$order[0]])

        $disableoutput = $currentListOrder.Remove($currentListOrder[0])

        foreach($ctToAdd in $order | where { $_ -ne $order[0]})
        {
            $currentListOrder.Add($list.ContentTypes[$ctToAdd])
        }

        $list.RootFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder = $currentListOrder
        $list.RootFolder.Update()
    }

    $web.Dispose()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to display the "New" button, it can be hidden using JSON formatting.

Navigate to the list or document library >> Click on the View dropdown and choose “Format current view” >> Click on “Advanced Mode”

Paste the JSON below to hide the New button from the toolbar.

```
{
  "commandBarProps" : {
    "commands": [
      {
        "key": "new",
        "hide": true
      }   
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

[Hide a Button in SharePoint Online List or document library Toolbar](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2022/03/hide-button-in-sharepoint-online-list-or-document-library.html)

Comment: Thanks for the input but I would like to keep this as a last resort. The only problem with this approach is that I will have to manually do it for each environment.

Comment: I also recommend you hide the "New" button using JSON formatting. In addition, you can use CSS code to hide the "New" button. For reference:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/545423/hide-new-button-in-sp-online-list-view-in-site-pag